# Insert alternating row of data into ListView in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView that displays a list of dates. What I want to do is insert a row of data in between each of these rows, that shows the time difference between the dates. Such as:

```
|Title: Red Date: 21/01/2021 4:45pm|
|5 hours 10 mins|
|Title: Green Date: 21/01/2021 10:25pm|
|55 mins|
|Title: Blue Date: 21/01/2021 9:30am|
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Would try to implement it shortly :)
Can you provide list of dates, it would help a lot.

Comment: you could do so inside the `itemBuilder` function where you would return a column that has the date, and the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coded this.

```
List<DateTime> dates = [DateTime.now(), DateTime.utc(1998, 2, 11)]; 

Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: dates.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('${DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(dates[index])}'),
              ),

                if(index < dates.length - 1)
               Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 child: Text('${dates[index].difference(dates[index + 1]).inHours} hours  ${dates[index].difference(dates[index + 1]).inMinutes.remainder(60)} minute'),
               )

              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Note: **Refer to this document for details on DateTime formatting.**
https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html